# Why doesn't a useEffect hook trigger with an object in the dependency array?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I'm noticing something really strange while working with hooks, I've got the following:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const [dependency1, setDependency1] = useState({});
const [dependency2, setDependency2] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("dependency 1 got an update");
}, [dependency1]);

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("dependency 2 got an update");
}, [dependency2]);

setInterval(() => {
  setDependency1(prevDep1 => {
    const _key = "test_" + Math.random().toString();
    if (prevDep1[_key] === undefined) prevDep1[_key] = [];
    else prevDep1[key].push("foo");
    return prevDep1;
  })
  setDependency2(prevDep2 => [...prevDep2, Math.random()]);
}, 1000);
```

for some reason only the useEffect with `dependency2` *(the array where items get added)* triggers, the one with `dependency1` *(the object where keys get added)* doesn't trigger..

**Why is this happening, and how can I make it work?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
setInterval(() => {
    setDependency1(prevDep1 => {
      const _key = "test_" + Math.random().toString();
      return {...prevDep1, [_key]: [...(prevDep1[_key] || []), 'foo']   }
    })
    setDependency2(prevDep2 => [...prevDep2, Math.random()]);
  }, 1000);
```

State should be updated in an immutable way.

Answer (score 3):

React will only check for reference equality when deciding a dependency changed, so if the old and new values pass a `===` check, it considers it unchanged.

In your first dependency you simply added a key to the existing object, thus not changing the actual object. The second dependency actually gets replaced altogether when spreading the old values into a new array.

Comment: I updated my question so it returns something, but it still does not work..

Comment: The last paragraph is no longer valid, but the other point remains true. As long as the old and new props pass a reference equality check `===` it will not trigger a change.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning an assignment statement here:

```
setDependency1(prevDep1 => prevDep1["test_" + Math.random().toString()] = ["foo"]);
```

You should return an object. Maybe something like:

```
setDependency1(prevDep1 => ({ ...prevDep1, ["test_" + Math.random().toString()]: ["foo"] }));
```

Comment: but what if I have to use if-statements?

Comment: Remove the short return syntax and use it like a normal function. (e.g `prevDep1 => { if (someCondition) { return someValue; } else { return otherValue; } }`)

Comment: that unfortunately doesn't work either, see my updated question please..

Comment: Check @Mordechai 's answer. He has already pointed out the problem. The equality check fails because you're returning the same object every time. You could try replacing `return prevDep1` with `return { ...prevDep1 }`